# DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body description: This field is required for slash json

Tags: discord, discord.js

I get the following error whenever I run my bot:

```cmd
  method: 'put',
  path: '/applications/[botID]/commands',
  code: 50035,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: [
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
    ],
    files: []
  }
```

and upon removing the `unhandledRejection` error catcher from my `index.js`, The console showed the JSON of my slash commands that go right under the `module.exports` but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my descriptions.
Here's an example of one of my JSON heads:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "ping",
  description: "Discord API Latency",
  cooldown: 0,
  async execute(client, interaction, Discord, guild) {
    const pingEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Pong! <:ping_pong:879164522307411998>")
      .setDescription(`My ping is ${Math.round(client.ws.ping)}ms`)
      .setColor("#000000");
    interaction.reply({ embeds: [pingEmbed] });
  },
};
```

Comment: Can we see more of your code?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what more to show since I'm pretty sure that's where the errors are originating from in all my commands. I just showed the kick command as an example.

Comment: We can't help you more if you don't show more sadly, the error said what is the problem, the description field is missing/errored.

Comment: I edited the original post with my complete ping command that also causes an error.

Comment: Can you check at which line the error occured?

Comment: I wish I could but all I get is the error saying `Invalid Form Body description: This field is required` with a few paths to node_module files. However, when I removed the error catcher found in the [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/errors.html#how-to-diagnose-api-errors), I was shown all of my json headers for my slash commands including options and such.

Comment: Can we see your entire slash command definitions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240493/discussion-between-fallenhero-and-leau).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this `const pingEmbed = new MessageEmbed()` you're using v13 right? I think it will work